# PYTHON: shape=(None,) + state_dim

Tags: python

In python,  is that `shape=(None,)+stat_dim` equal to `shape=(None, state_dim)`?
If they are the same, why bother writting in that way?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not the same.

Let's try it with some examples:

```
>>> stat_dim = (1, 2, 3)
>>> (None,) + stat_dim
(None, 1, 2, 3)
>>> (1, 2) + (3, 4)
(1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> shape = (None,) + stat_dim
>>> shape[2]
2
```

This concatenates two tuples into a single tuple. So, you get a 4-element tuple that's just like the 3-element tuple `stat_dim`, but with the extra value `None` at the start.

---

```
>>> (None, stat_dim)
(None, (1, 2, 3))
>>> ((1, 2), (3, 4))
((1, 2), (3, 4)
```

This creates a two-element tuple, whose first element is `None`, and whose second element is the `stat_dim` tuple.

So now there is no `shape[2]`; there's only `shape[0]` and `shape[1]`, and then `shape[1]` has its own elements:

```
>>> shape = (None, stat_dim)
>>> shape[2]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
>>> shape[1][2]
3
```